# Python Mechanize: selecting an option

Tags: javascript, python, html

How do i select an option from the select tag?

This form contains only one select tag and no submit button. When an option is selected, it is supposed to call the javascript function __doPostBack('D1','') which adds more content to the same page.

```
    <select name="D1" onchange="__doPostBack('D1','')" language="javascript" id="D1">
    <option value="0">- Select -</option>
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="3">option2</option>
    <option value="5">option3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have that much experience with mechanize, I believe it should be something like this:

```
control = form.find_control('D1')
control.value = ['3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `WWW:Mechanize` does not have a Javascript engine. It's said here : http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html#script

There are some workaround, but it's not sure the method will work 100% of the time.

```
#Changing the control
br.select_form(nr=0) # select the first form : try to locate your form and adapt the line
form = br.form
form['D1'] = ['3']

#Submitting the changes
request2 = form.click()  # mechanize.Request object
try:
    response2 = mechanize.urlopen(request2)
except mechanize.HTTPError, response2:
    pass
```

The other solution is to automate a headless browser (like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) with `PhantomJS` )